# kubernetes: is it possible to add labels to individual containers?

Tags: kubernetes

In kubernetes, Deployments can have labels. But in my situation, I need the actual containers in a pod to have certain labels that triggers some action to be carried out by an agent on the node.

Is there a way to add specific labels to containers in Kubernetes?

Comment: No: https://kubernetes.io/docs/resources-reference/v1.5/#container-v1. But please elaborate more on this "that triggers some action to be carried out by an agent on the node."?

Answer (score 2):

You can't add a label to individual containers, only to the pod in which they are running. I'd suggest rather than using labels (which is for identifying info) to leverage pod [annotations](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/overview/working-with-objects/annotations/), potentially along with the [downward API](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/inject-data-application/downward-api-volume-expose-pod-information/) for triggering actions.

Comment: does annotations get converted into lables on containers?

Comment: No. Both are orthogonal metadata pieces on the pod-level.